# Magmi: how to import categories from different columns

Tags: magento, magmi

I have a CSV with 2 columns for categories. 1 column contains the base category of the product and second column contains the sub-category of the product. If no sub is specified the product is considered to belong to the base category. 
Is there a way to instruct magmi and tell him that the categories should be created from 2 different columns and that column 1 is base category and column 2 sub-category ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, its is perfectly possible through the Value Replacer plugin (from extra package)

see documentation [here](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Value_Replacer) (there's even a category from multiple columns sample in simple syntax paragraph):

Comment: can you please give your solution here because when i go to this link it takes me to home page every time . I need this so urgently. So now its your time to save my life :)